# Extract the top n lines from a .zip file that is password protected

Tags: unix, zip, cygwin, dos, zcat

We have multiple large .zip files (500 GB+ compressed, 5 TB+ uncompressed).
Each .zip file contains one compressed file, that compressed file is password protected.

We would like to use either a UNIX (Cygwin) or DOS command to extract around 100 rows from the top and a 100 rows from the bottom of the password protected single compressed file that is contained within the .zip file.

It appears that the `zcat` command affords us the ability to specify `head` and `tail` commands allowing us to extract portions of the compressed file without having to unzip the entire file.  The issue we're running into is that the compressed file is password protected and we don't know if there is a utility we can use to specify the password on the command line and allow the file to be read by `zcat`, without having to fully unzip the file.

Is it possible for us to somehow combine the `zcat` command with another command which would unlock the password protection on the compressed file and redirect the top 100 and bottom 100 rows of the compressed file to an output.txt file?

Comment: I don't understand the point of your question: Are you trying to crack the password?

Comment: We have the password.   The question was how to open the file and look at a small portion of records without having to fully unzip it since it’s huge.  Thanks!

Comment: If the zip contains only a single file, you can't look at parts of it without extracting the whole file. It does not mean that you have to extract it to disk. If you can extract it to stdout, you can pipe it to `less` and then page through the file, without causing a permanent copy to be stored. See the `-c` option of `unzip`. Of course, if the unzipped file is in the TB range, `less` will most likely allocate a temporary file (and get rid of it afterwards), so if you don't have enough diskspace, you will be in trouble.

Comment: You could write a small utility, which reads stdin, and prints the first n and the last n lines from it, discarding the rest. If you `unzip -c YOUR_FILE.zip| ...` to such a utility, you could get the desired result, without the need of large disk space. Still, this assumes that `unzip` does not need a temporary file for its task, but I think it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

`zcat` is used to extract *gzipped* files; it does not work with `.zip` archives. Even if it were, to get the last lines of a compressed file, you'd still need to decompress the full file – unless the compression algorithm specfically allows only decompressing part of a compressed file (which would yield worse compression rates).